# Boost::Spirit and Intel compiler compile error

Tags: boost-spirit, icc

I wrote a mathematical expression parser using Boost Spirit that parses a simple power expression (minimal example of a much larger parser):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct power_ {
    template <typename X, typename Y> struct result {
        typedef X type;
    };

    template <typename X, typename Y> X operator()(X x, Y y) const {
        return std::pow(x, y);
    }
};

struct math : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, double(),
                          ascii::space_type> {
    math() : math::base_type(expr) {
        boost::phoenix::function<power_> power;

        expr = factor[qi::_val = qi::_1];

        factor = arg[qi::_val = qi::_1] >>
                 *("**" >> arg [qi::_val = power(qi::_val, qi::_1)]);

        arg = qi::double_[qi::_val = qi::_1];
    }

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> expr, arg, factor;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    math math;

    string expr = "2**3";
    double result;

    string::const_iterator iter = expr.begin();
    string::const_iterator end = expr.end();
    phrase_parse(iter, end, math, ascii::space, result);

    cout << "Expression: " << expr << endl;
    cout << "Result: " << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine using both GCC 4.8.4 and Clang 3.9, but gives a huge compilation error when compiling using the Intel compiler (version 12.1.6). The relevant part of the compiler output is

```
/user/home/gent/vsc408/vsc40826/boost_1_60_0/build/include/boost/utility/result_of.hpp(189): error: too few arguments for class template "power_::result"
  struct result_of_nested_result : F::template result<FArgs>
```

This seems to point at an issue with boost::result_of and C++11, as mentioned by http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of. However, when I change the definition of `struct power_`:

```
struct power_ {
    template <class> struct result;

    template <class F, typename X, typename Y>
    struct result < F(X, Y) > {
        typedef X type;
    };

    template <typename X, typename Y> X operator()(X x, Y y) const {
        return std::pow(x, y);
    }
};
```

I still get an error:

```
/user/home/gent/vsc408/vsc40826/boost_1_60_0/build/include/boost/phoenix/core/detail/preprocessed/function_eval_10.hpp(135): error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
                  return boost::phoenix::eval(f, ctx)(help_rvalue_deduction(boost::phoenix::eval(a0, ctx)) , help_rvalue_deduction(boost::phoenix::eval(a1, ctx)));
```

Adding `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` before any spirit includes does not help either, as compilation then fails on the first spirit include.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The problem only occurs for Boost versions higher than 1.56.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just figured this one out. Boost::Phoenix apparently switched to return by reference. The following version of `struct power_` works:

```
struct power_ {
    template <class> struct result;

    template <class F, typename X, typename Y>
    struct result < F(X, Y) > {
        typedef X& type;
    };

    template <typename X, typename Y> X& operator()(X &x, Y y) const {
        x = std::pow(x, y);
        return x;
    }
};
```